# Symfony Mapping in Doctrine without Annotations or XML Files

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

a customer has an existing database. The schema is often changed within the database itself (e.g. he adds a new column).

My task is to develop an admin area with symfony that automatically reacts on table schema changes without modifying the application code. E.g. the customer adds a new column to table "MyEntity", and the application automatically generates a new column in the accordingly list view.

My approach is to dynamically map the table columns to the Entity class so that ALL Attributes and ALL Getters/Setters are generated dynamically from the table schema.

So is it possible to map the table columns in a Doctrine Entity without the use of Annotations or XML Files.

Something like:

```
class MyEntity{

   public function generateMappingFromSchema($sTableName){...}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do that. Doctrine was not designed for such use case.

There is a library though you should check https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/fluent which basically is a mapping driver that allows you to manage your mappings in an Object Oriented approach. And there are other tools:

http://crud-admin-generator.com/
http://crudkit.com/
http://www.grocerycrud.com/

which are maybe better for that, I don't know.

But again, **please don't do that**. Do not allow the customer to modify the database schema or give them e.g. a [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) which was designed for that.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.

I know that allowing users to modify the database is not good at all but this is part of what they want. Otherwise they would look for someone else.

I will check your suggestions.

Comment: If they don't understand why it's bad, than maybe that would be better for you :) (but it's your business not mine and it's just my offtopic opinion, which you didn't asked anyway :)).